# Web app http 404 error in azure but runs locally

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-sql-database, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to create a web api that connects to my Azure SQL database and reads from the data, I used the 'API' template from VS19 and adding my own files, I ran the app locally (the templates weather forecast worked fine) and I tested my API using postman. I then deployed my api directly from VS to my app service in Azure but when I go to the URL I get the following error:

> This securedmessaging.azurewebsites.net page can’t be foundNo web page
> was found for the web address:
> https://****.azurewebsites.net/ HTTP ERROR 404

Can someone please help me run the app from azure as it runs locally? Im not sure where I went wrong. Below is a picture of my solution explorer.

[image]

Comment: How did you publish? what do you have inside wwwroot?

Comment: hi @sajeetharan, I went into build, publish and published it to my azure app service I had already created, I cant seem to find a file for wwwroot, do you know where this would be sorry?

Comment: Just navigate to https://securedmessaging.scm.azurewebsites.net and you can see the wwwroot

Comment: refer this document for publish from visual studio
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-deploy-web-app-to-azure-using-visual-studio/

Comment: Hi @Reeves62, please check the kudu site what Sajeetharan provided in comment, if you there are any files missed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> web page was found for the web address: https://securedmessaging.azurewebsites.net/ HTTP ERROR 404

You mentioned that the app is a ASP.NET Core Web API app that does not include and serve a default page, so that it would cause a ***404 Not Found*** error while you access the site without a fully qualified URI.

To make request to API endpoint, you can try:

```
https://securedmessaging.azurewebsites.net/WeatherForecast
```

Or

```
https://securedmessaging.azurewebsites.net/api/brokers/{action_name_here}
```

Besides, if you'd like to serve a default page that's displayed at the root URL for a website, you can try:

*1) Create `Default.html` under wwwroot folder*

[image]

*2)Call the `UseDefaultFiles` method in `Configure` method of `Startup.cs`*

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: Ah brilliant, this worked from both checking using the API end point and adding in a default html page. thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

In my case following lines were missing from Startup.cs

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            }
        );
```

Adding these lines in the configuration section of the startup.cs fixed the issue.