# how to visit a html page which is directly put in kudu home/site/wwwroot?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I have a .net core 3.1 mvc project, and published to azure web app. Then in kudu -> home/site/wwwroot, I created a html file, like below:
[image]

But when I want to visit the html page via azure web app like this "https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/test111.html", it has 404 error:
[image]

Are there any way to fix this, from code or azure portal?

Comment: You can refer to [Web app http 404 error in azure but runs locally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64167489/15969115)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have an ASP.NET Core app? Have you enabled serving of static files, re:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: we can use this line of code, then it can wok in azure:   app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                env.ContentRootPath)
            });

Comment: Did `app.UseStaticFiles` does not work?